# Calculation in SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g, calculation

I am performing the following Oracle select on sqldeveloper:

```
select  (2299) / (((2299) * 20 )/ (100 * 360)) from dual;
```

and it is giving me

```
1800.000000000000000000000000000000000003
```

as a result instead of **1800**, why is that? and how can i fix it?

Comment: It seems to be a rounding error. How much precision - how many digits after the decimal point - do you need?

Comment: Do you want 1800 value. discarding the digits after decimal place?

Answer (score 0):

In these type of operations,the complex multiplication and division makes the answer to err by a very small amount as here its 0.0000000000000003 and is very common in database related operations,I had experienced the same error and simplifying the operation in 2 steps had given the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the rounding error you're seeing, you can round the calculated value to a smaller number of decimal places:

```
set numf 9999.999999999999999999999999999999999999
select  (2299) / (((2299) * 20 )/ (100 * 360)) from dual;

           (2299)/(((2299)*20)/(100*360))
-----------------------------------------
1800.000000000000000000000000000000000003

select  round((2299) / (((2299) * 20 )/ (100 * 360)), 35) from dual;

 ROUND((2299)/(((2299)*20)/(100*360)),35)
-----------------------------------------
1800.000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

(The trailing zeros are only showing now because of the number format I specified for display).

You could also, in this case at least, eliminate it by using binary arithmetic, but I'm not sure that's a good idea generally:

```
select  cast (2299 as binary_double) / (((2299) * 20 )/ (100 * 360)) from dual;

CAST(2299ASBINARY_DOUBLE)/(((2299)*20)/(100*360))
-------------------------------------------------
                                         1.8E+003
```

Answer (score 0):

Precision can not be specified when you don't define the data type.

You can cast the result or use TRUNC function

```
SELECT CAST ((2299) / (((2299) * 20 )/ (100 * 360))AS INT) FROM dual
```